# Flutter - Reducing unnecessary spacing inside Container

Tags: flutter

I want to remove spacing inside my container and I cannot seem to get it right, I tried using height but it still does not work.

my code:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) => SizedBox(
        height: 440,
        child: Container(
         //grey color
          color: CustomTheme().neutral100,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                xxLargePadding, xLargePadding, xxLargePadding, largePadding),
            child: ListView.separated(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                itemBuilder: (_, index) => Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          officials[index].fullName,
                          style: TextStyle(

                              fontSize: 12, color: CustomTheme().neutral500),//white color
                        ),
                        Text(
                          officials[index].type,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 12, color: CustomTheme().neutral400),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                separatorBuilder: (_, index) => const Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: largePadding),
                      child: Divider(),
                    ),
                itemCount: officials.length),
          ),
        ),
      );
```

The results looks like the screenshot below:
[image]

I want to remove the spacing at the top where I highlighted with red.
There seems to be something making that space, I just do not get it.

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are using `padding` inside the `container`, set `0` to `top` and `bottom` also set `listview` padding to `0`:

```
Container(
    //grey color
    color: CustomTheme().neutral100,
    child: Padding(
       padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(xxLargePadding, 0, xxLargePadding, 0), // <--- change this
       child: ListView.separated(
          padding:EdgeInsets.zero, // <--- add this
    ...
)
```

a tip for your code for cleaner code, change your `separatorBuilder` to this:

```
separatorBuilder: (_, index) => Divider(
   height: largePadding + 16,// largePadding + Divider's default height value
),
```

Comment: hi @eamirho3ein, still does not remove the spacing

Comment: @SaDev was it what you want?

Answer (score 0):

the padding property in the `ListView` takes by default an extra value, you need to set it to 0 like this:

```
 ListView(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
 // ...
```